# Django Array contains a field

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am using Django, with mongoengine. I have a model Classes with an inscriptions list, And I want to get the docs that have an id in that list.

`classes = Classes.objects.filter(inscriptions__contains=request.data['inscription'])`

Answer (score 10):

Here's a general explanation of querying ArrayField membership:

Per the [Django ArrayField docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#contains), the `__contains` operator checks if a provided array is a subset of the values in the ArrayField.

So, to filter on whether an ArrayField contains the value "foo", you pass in a length 1 array containing the value you're looking for, like this:

```
# matches rows where myarrayfield is something like ['foo','bar']
Customer.objects.filter(myarrayfield__contains=['foo'])
```

The Django ORM produces the `@>` [postgres operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html), as you can see by printing the query:

```
print Customer.objects.filter(myarrayfield__contains=['foo']).only('pk').query
>>> SELECT "website_customer"."id" FROM "website_customer" WHERE "website_customer"."myarrayfield_" @> ['foo']::varchar(100)[]
```

If you provide something other than an array, you'll get a cryptic error like `DataError: malformed array literal: "foo"   DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I'm missing something...but it seems that you should be using [`.filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter):

```
classes = Classes.objects.filter(inscriptions__contains=request.data['inscription'])
```

Comment: In fact it is working, didn't taught it work on arrays too. Thanks.
What is the difference between filter and the way I did ?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in reference to your comment for rnevius answer

In Django ORM whenever you make a Database call using ORM, it will generally return either a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api-reference) or  an object of the model if using [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get) / number if you are using [count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#count) ect., depending on the functions that you are using which return other than a queryset.

The result from a Queryset function can be used to implement further more refinement, like if you like to perform a order() or collecting only distinct() etc. Queryset are lazy which means it only hits the database when they are actually used not when they are assigned. You can find more information about them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/optimization/#understand-queryset-evaluation).

Where as the functions that doesn't return queryset cannot  implement such things.

Take time and go through the Queryset Documentation more in depth explanation with examples are provided. It is useful to understand the behavior to make your application more efficient.